# swift: Show progress in label in collection view

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

I use this code to download files and show progress of downloading in label and I create label in storyboard:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath) as! MasterViewCell

        let cellFilePath = "\(indexPath.section)\(indexPath.row).png"
        let indexOfTask = allDownloadTasks.index { (task:URLSessionDownloadTask) -> Bool in
            return task.currentRequest?.url?.lastPathComponent == cellFilePath
        }

        if indexOfTask == nil {

            //cell.label?.isHidden = true
        }
return cell
    }

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) { 

    let path = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(FileManager.SearchPathDirectory.documentDirectory, FileManager.SearchPathDomainMask.userDomainMask, true)
    let documentDirectoryPath:String = path[0]
    let fileManager = FileManager()
    let destinationURLForFile = URL(fileURLWithPath: documentDirectoryPath.appendingFormat("/file.png"))

     if fileManager.fileExists(atPath: destinationURLForFile.path){
         animation()
     } else {

         let url = URL(string: "link")!
         let downloadTaskLocal = self.backgroundSession.downloadTask(with: url)
         self.allDownloadTasks.append(downloadTaskLocal) // Add a new task to the array
         downloadTaskLocal.resume()

         cell.label?.frame = CGRect(x: 70, y: 128, width: 82, height: 21)
         cell.label?.isHidden = false

     }
}

func urlSession(_ session: URLSession,
                    downloadTask: URLSessionDownloadTask,
                    didWriteData bytesWritten: Int64,
                    totalBytesWritten: Int64,
                    totalBytesExpectedToWrite: Int64){

        DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: {() -> Void in

            if let visibleIndexPath = self.collectionView?.indexPathsForVisibleItems {
                for visibleIndexPath in visibleIndexPath {
                    if (downloadTask.currentRequest?.url?.lastPathComponent == "\(visibleIndexPath.section)\(visibleIndexPath.row).zip") {

                        var myCell = self.collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "Cell", for: visibleIndexPath) as! MasterViewCell
                        myCell = self.collectionView?.cellForItem(at: visibleIndexPath) as! MasterViewCell

                        myCell.label.text = "\(Int(CGFloat(totalBytesWritten) / CGFloat(totalBytesExpectedToWrite) * 100.0))%"

                    }
                }
            }
        })
    }
```

But I have two problems:

1. If I downloaded 6 files(press on 6 cells) and after that want to continue download different files and I press on next cell. My label in cell not showing but download works. Also if I will start download in another cells my download will be works fine but label not will be showing. How to fix it?
2. If I downloaded file and my label = 100 in this cell after that I scroll my collection view in next section and I see in some different cells label = 100. But I not downloaded files in this cells.

Comment: can you show your `cellforitematindexpath` ?

Comment: @mnemonic23 updated question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your cell is being reused. Make sure you reset your cell in `prepareForReuse` method inside the cell class. Also make sure you store the progress of each cell and set it whenever a cell is being dequeued in `cellForRowAt` method.

```
class MasterViewCell {

  override func prepareForReuse() {
      label.text = "0" //or whatever is supposed to be value for the default cell.
      // Do other operations to clear your cell of any existing data for reused cells.
  }

}
```

For saving progress, just declare a variable array and save the data in that array at the respective index. When you dequeue a cell, check the array and use the value in the array. I see that you have a method called `urlSession` where you know the indexPath of the cell on which the progress is happening. Just store the value of that in an array at that index.

Comment: After that I should use `prepareForReuse `? How to I need to save the progress?

Comment: `prepareForReuse` is a method inside your cell class which can be overriden to do whatever you need to do when a cell is reused. Since you are reusing cells, an already updated cell may show up as a new cell. So to get a fresh cell, you need reset label and whatever change you made to a cell to default values inside `prepareForReuse` of your cell. To save progress you can store the values of the progress whenever they update in an array.

Comment: Could you please show some example? How to use it in my case. Because now I can't quite understand when I should use `prepareForReuse ` and when save progress.

Comment: Edited my answer.

Comment: Thank you! Could you check please - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51629230/swift-show-uiactivityindicatorview-when-file-unzipping#51629599

Answer (score 0):

You are reusing cells so it is happening. You have to create your data source properly for the cells. For example you can create a `Download` class and in this class you must have all the information regarding download and its progress. In this class only you must write the download code and progress tracking. And you should use this class object array for your cell data source, so that you get all the info. related to the download while reusing the cell. Please check the below link this will help you doing this.

https://www.raywenderlich.com/158106/urlsession-tutorial-getting-started